# How to store the module of "vuex-module-decorators" in Vue class component with minimal performance impact?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, vue-property-decorator, vuex-module-decorators

The simplest way to store the `vuex` module in `Vue` component is:

```js
import { Vue, Component } from "vue-property-decorator";
import { getModule } from "vuex-module-decorators";
import ExampleModule from "@Store/ExampleModule";


@Component
class ExampleComponent extends Vue {

  private exampleModule: ExampleModule = getModule(ExampleModule);

  private reuse(): void {
    this.exampleModule.stateField1;
  }

  private reuseAgain(): void {
    this.exampleModule.stateField2;
  }
}
```

Now, the whole `exampleModule` is reactive data of the Vue component. Is it all right?